# SLR of transformed data in R

Tags: r

For Y = % of population with income below poverty level and X = per capita income of population, I have constructed a box-cox plot and found that the lambda = 0.02020:

```
bc <- boxcox(lm(Percent_below_poverty_level ~ Per_capita_income, data=tidy.CDI), plotit=T)
bc$x[which.max(bc$y)] # gives lambda
```

Now I want to fit a simple linear regression using the transformed data, so I've entered this code

```
transform <- lm((Percent_below_poverty_level**0.02020) ~ (Per_capita_income**0.02020))
transform
```

But all I get is the error message
'Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid power in formula'. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `bcPower()` from the `car` package.

```
## make sure you do install.packages("car") if you haven't already
library(car)
data(Prestige)
p <- powerTransform(prestige ~ income + education + type , 
                    data=Prestige, 
                    family="bcPower")

summary(p)
# bcPower Transformation to Normality 
# Est Power Rounded Pwr Wald Lwr Bnd Wald Upr Bnd
# Y1    1.3052           1       0.9408       1.6696
# 
# Likelihood ratio test that transformation parameter is equal to 0
# (log transformation)
# LRT df       pval
# LR test, lambda = (0) 41.67724  1 1.0765e-10
# 
# Likelihood ratio test that no transformation is needed
# LRT df    pval
# LR test, lambda = (1) 2.623915  1 0.10526

mod <- lm(bcPower(prestige, 1.3052) ~ income + education + type, data=Prestige)
summary(mod)
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = bcPower(prestige, 1.3052) ~ income + education + 
#        type, data = Prestige)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -44.843 -13.102   0.287  15.073  62.889 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) -3.736e+01  1.639e+01  -2.279   0.0250 *  
#   income       3.363e-03  6.928e-04   4.854 4.87e-06 ***
#   education    1.205e+01  2.009e+00   5.999 3.78e-08 ***
#   typeprof     2.027e+01  1.213e+01   1.672   0.0979 .  
# typewc      -1.078e+01  7.884e+00  -1.368   0.1746    
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 22.25 on 93 degrees of freedom
# (4 observations deleted due to missingness)
# Multiple R-squared:  0.8492,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8427 
# F-statistic:   131 on 4 and 93 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 1):

Powers (more often represented by `^` than `**` in R, FWIW) have a special meaning inside formulas [they represent interactions among variables rather than mathematical operations]. So if you did want to power-transform both sides of your equation you would use the `I()` or "as-is" operator:

```
I(Percent_below_poverty_level^0.02020) ~ I(Per_capita_income^0.02020)
```

**However**, I think you should do what @DaveArmstrong suggested anyway:

- it's only the predictor variable that gets transformed
- the [Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) is actually `(y^lambda-1)/lambda` (although the shift and scale might not matter for your results)